# How Do I Center Items on My Navbar Only on Small Devices Using Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Recently I have been using Tailwind CSS to create a basic navbar for my site. I have it so a button disappears when you are on a small device but I would also like to have the item's centre when I use it on a small device. Here is the code that I have.

```
    <!-- navbar goes here -->
    <nav class="bg-gray-100">
        <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-8" >
            <div class="flex justify-between">  
                <div class="flex space-x-4 sd:items-center">
                    <!-- logo -->
                        <div>
                            <a href="#" class="flex items-center py-4 px-2 text-gray-700">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 mr-2 text-green-400" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9.663 17h4.673M12 3v1m6.364 1.636l-.707.707M21 12h-1M4 12H3m3.343-5.657l-.707-.707m2.828 9.9a5 5 0 117.072 0l-.548.547A3.374 3.374 0 0014 18.469V19a2 2 0 11-4 0v-.531c0-.895-.356-1.754-.988-2.386l-.548-.547z" />
                                </svg>
                                <span>JRRNZ's Stats</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <!-- primary nav -->
                        <div class="flex items-center space-x-1">
                            <a href="" class="py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-blue-400">Bedwars</a>
                            <a href="" class="py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-blue-400">Skywars</a>
                            <a href="" class="py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 rounded hover:bg-blue-400">Bazaar</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                    <!-- secondary nav -->
                    <div class="hidden md:flex flex items-center space-x-1">
                        <a class="py-5 px-3">
                            <a href="nabartest.html">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5 mr-2 rounded hover:text-green-400" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 4v5h.582m15.356 2A8.001 8.001 0 004.582 9m0 0H9m11 11v-5h-.581m0 0a8.003 8.003 0 01-15.357-2m15.357 2H15" />
                                </svg>
                            </a>
                        </a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

On line 5 you can see the attempt I have made by using sd:items-center. If anyone has any solutions or needs any more information please let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to center it vertically or horizontally? Here's my answer for either:

First things first, you have to keep in mind that tailwindcss, like many frameworks out there is "mobile-first". Meaning the styles get applied starting with small screens; anything beyond that, you'll have to specify. Eg, lets say you have a div which should have a background of red only on small devices but green on the rest of the screens, here's what you'll need to do: `<div class="bg-red md:bg-green"></div>`. This will apply `bg-green` to device sizes `md` and above but small screen will still use `bg-red`.

With that said, if you're looking to center align the navbar vertically you have to change the `sd:items-center` to `items-center` in line 5.

However, if you're looking to center align the navbar items horizontally (which I think is what you're trying to achieve), you'll need to change the `justify-between` in line 4 to `justify-center md:justify-between`. You can remove `sd:items-center` as it has no meaning. No breakpoint named `sd:` exists in tailwindcss.

Check this out:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/cv0Hw6QcWz?size=746x720